# Prove that for two non-empty events $A$ and $B$, $P(A|B) \le P(A)$ implies $P(B|A) \ge P(B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove that for two non-empty events $A$ and $B$, $P(A|B) \le P(A)$ implies $P(B|A) \ge P(B)$ was in my lecture notes; however I disagree with the statement.

As my counter example, let $P(B) = 0.7$ and $P(A) = 0.4$ and $P(B \cap A) = 0.1$. Here we have that $P(A|B)= \dfrac {P(A \cap B)} {P(B)} = \dfrac {0.1} {0.7} \le P(A) = 0.4$ and $P(B | A)= \dfrac {P(A \cap B)} {P(A)} = \dfrac {0.1} {0.4} \le P(B) = 0.7$.

I am thinking that perhaps they made a typo in signs?

$P(A|B) \le P(A)$ implies $P(B|A) \le P(B)$ seems true to me, given that $ P(B|A) = \dfrac { P(B) * P(A|B) } {P(A)} \le P(B) $.

We can make a similar argument with reversed signs.

Is there some error in my logic? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample, your proposed correction to the problem, and your proof of that proposed correction, all appear correct to me.